# In regular expression: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Tags: javascript, regex

I used the following expression

```
str.match(tag+"(\s*=\s*)((['"]*)(.+?)(['"]*)\1)");
```

where str is the string to be matched with and tag is a variable

For example the above expression should match

```
m="img"
m='img'
```

where tag=m;
But at the above mentioned lined I'm getting

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Comment: i even tried `str.match(tag+"(\s*=\s*)((['\"]*)(.+?)(['\"]*)\1)");` but the result is showing null

Comment: what language is this code for?

Comment: I am using this in javascript

Answer (score 2):

If you remove /1 from the end of the regexp, it works for m="img":

```
m(\s*=\s*)((['\"]*)(.*)(['\"]*))
```

"\1" is replaced with the value of the first subpattern within the pattern so if you would like to match m="img";m='img' you should use the following:

```
(m\s*=\s*)((['\"]*)(.*)(['\"]*)\1)
```

where m is your tag variable.

EDIT:
you can test your javascript regexps [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).

Answer (score 1):

- As was stated, quotes should be escaped.
- backreference should be escaped too.
- once you use backreference, second group with quote is not needed,
- it is third parethesis group, which contain quotes, hence you need \3, not \1
- and hardly you need to match any amount of quotes like: `m = '''img'''`

Taking all these points into account, one may get the following solution:

```
var tag = 'm';
"m='img'".match(tag+"(\s*=\s*)((['\"]?)(.+?)\\3)")
// ["m='img'", "=", "'img'", "'", "img"]
```

Comment: What is your example, which result in `null`?

Comment: var m="img";
s1 = document.createElement(m);
s1.src="http://www.cdac.com"; i am retrieving m successfully and for getting the tag name i am using the above expression which is resulting null

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't see the code, where you're using this expression.

Comment: var m="img";
s1 = document.createElement(m);
s1.src="http://www.cdac.com";var y=str.match(tag+"(\s*=\s*)((['\"]*)(.+?)\3)");

Comment: Maybe, you understood me wrong. I want to see not data, but code, how you are using it. If you mean string with that js code, it is working, i.e. matching `m="img"`.